# java login system

Tags: java, encryption, md5, login-script

I am trying to make a multi user login system for my java program, at the moment i am compairing the username and password to md5 hashes stored in a text file. I would like to be able to geive different users different access wrights to the program, using the system i am using at the moment the accesablility would be easy to change if the text file was opend. Is there a way I could encrypt the text in the file and then unencrypt it when the user loggs in??? Thanks

Comment: Can you use a database instead?

Comment: I am new to java so I dont know how to use/make a database with java, but it sounds like a good way to solve the problem!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look at [this](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/security/jce/JCERefGuide.html) comprehensive Java Cryptography guide. However, I think that you would be better off with a database to store the username and password since a text file could be easily deleted or modified. Encrypting it only makes it tougher to read.

Please take a look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/usingmysql/java/) and [here](http://www.kitebird.com/articles/jdbc.html) to learn about JDBC. If you want a more robust framework, you can use and ORM like [hibernate](http://www.hibernate.org/). The links I have posted refer to MySQL. It is a very popular Database server and integrates well with Java. You shouldn't have any problems finding tutorials or any kind of help with MySQL.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at JAAS to restrict access to your services (e.g. based on roles).

Comment: Here a link how to configure a JDBCRealm in GlassFish:
http://blogs.sun.com/swchan/entry/jdbcrealm_in_glassfish

Answer (score 0):

Md5 is a one way hash algorithmic you cant decrypt it back , best way is to compare the encrypted string to validate things

Answer (score 0):

Does this help:

[Java - encrypt / decrypt user name and password from a configuration file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/339004/java-encrypt-decrypt-user-name-and-password-from-a-configuration-file)

Comment: The system is offline so it would have to be stored on the computer. Thanks