# Convert Encryption Algorithm from VB.NET to Java (Android)

Tags: java, android, vb.net, encryption

i'm using the following algorithm to encrypt and decrypt a string in VB.NET and wanted to do that same method in Android also. can anyone tell me the similar algorithm for Android (Java)

**Encryption:**

```
Private Function decryptStr(ByVal key As String, ByVal enc As String) As String
    Try
        DES.Key = Hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key))
        DES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESDecrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateDecryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = Convert.FromBase64String(enc)
        respass = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(DESDecrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return respass
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return enc
    End Try
End Function
```

**Decryption:**

```
Public Function decryptStr(ByVal encrypted As String, ByVal key As String) As String
    Try
        DES.Key = Hash.ComputeHash(System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(key))
        DES.Mode = System.Security.Cryptography.CipherMode.ECB
        Dim DESEncrypter As System.Security.Cryptography.ICryptoTransform = DES.CreateEncryptor
        Dim Buffer As Byte() = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(encrypted)
        respass = Convert.ToBase64String(DESEncrypter.TransformFinalBlock(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length))
        Return respass
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return encrypted
    End Try
End Function
```

Comment: Just have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220761/fast-and-simple-string-encrypt-decrypt-in-java).

Comment: Which hashing algorithm is used (see initialization of "Hash" variable)?

Answer (score 0):

1. For the Cipher, use `Cipher.getInstance("DES/ECB/PKCS5Padding")`
2. For getting the bytes to input in the hash function to get the key, use `String.getBytes(key, Charset.forName("ASCII"))` and `new String(keyData, Charset.forName("ASCII"))` the other way round
3. Use the (as yet unspecified) hash function. Make sure you set the key size to 8 bytes afterwards, as DES only needs 8 characters for the key. Something like `MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5")` or `"SHA1"` should do the trick.
4. Create the key by simply performing `new SecretKeySpec(<my 8 byte byte array>, "DES")`
5. Base 64 encoding/Decoding  is not installed by default, look into commons-codec from Apache to do this.

If you use character encodings at several places, just create a constant:

```
private static final Charset ASCII = Charset.forName("ASCII");
```

The new and improved way of getting part of a byte array is:

```
Arrays.copyOfRange(byte[] original, int from, int to): byte[]
```