# How do I encrypt and Decrypt Txt file to/from external storage Android?

Tags: java, android

I know how to Write and Read data from External Storage, I don't know How to encrypt and decrypt this data to my external storage, so that whoever is trying to access that file using file explorer, It should be encrypted.

Here I have written the for storing and reading the data, for which I am using the buttons.

```
    public class SOSActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public EditText contact1;
    Button saveButton, readButton;
    private Context context;
    public SharedPreferences.Editor editorcache;

    private String filename = "SampleFile.txt";
    private String filepath = "MyFileStorage";
    File myExternalFile;
    String myData = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sos);

    context = this.getApplicationContext();

    saveButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    contact1 = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact1));

        saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            try {
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(myExternalFile);
                fos.write(contact1.getText().toString().getBytes());
                fos.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            // response.setText("SampleFile.txt saved to External
            // Storage...");
            finish();
        }

    });

    readButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.read);

    readButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            contact1.setText("");
            try {
                FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(myExternalFile);
                DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(fis);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
                String strLine;
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    myData = myData + strLine;
                }
                in.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            contact1.setText(myData);
            // response.setText("SampleFile.txt data retrieved from Internal
            // Storage...");
        }
    });

    if (!isExternalStorageAvailable() || isExternalStorageReadOnly()) {
        saveButton.setEnabled(false);
    } else {
        myExternalFile = new File(getExternalFilesDir(filepath), filename);
    }
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageReadOnly() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED_READ_ONLY.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

private static boolean isExternalStorageAvailable() {
    String extStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if (Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(extStorageState)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow the link to explore 2-way encryption.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175319/2761151

**Warning:** This method may not work for Android N

Comment: I understood the concept, but how do I implement it in my code, can you help me with that... thanks for the solution

Comment: Encrypt your text right before you save onto file. Something like this.

String myText =contact1.getText().toString(); 
String ecryptedText = encrypt(myText); 
fos.write(ecryptedText.getBytes());