# How to protect the AdMob App ID in Android manifest?

Tags: android, admob

To add AdMob to an Android application, the following is required in the manifest:

`android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
 android:value="YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID"`

Is there any way to protect YOUR_ADMOB_APP_ID from being visible as plain text 
here? It is exposed in the release apk-file with just a use of an archiver

Comment: see my answer at : https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999425/12936324
this is work for me

Comment: see my answer at this link this is working for me [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73999425/12936324)

Answer (score 1):

Good question. Yes AdMob app id can be easily visible to people with basic computer knowledge.

But why concern? It is only a key and not a password to steal your information in AdMob. Do you expect a hacker to use this key in his app, just for the purpose of increasing your AdMob income?

Comment: What if they produce fake clicks on your AdMod AppId to make Google ban your account?

Comment: @Liar  that is not easy. AppID is not the only information to produce an AdRequest, other information is not in manifest.

Comment: I'm a bit concern about this, since they can make invalid clicks resulting to account suspension. You can read more from https://support.google.com/admob/answer/6213019?hl=en

Answer (score 0):

Try encrypting your Id string using [Cipher](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/crypto/Cipher.html).

Check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175319/4224024) for detailed implemetation.

When someone decompiles your code, they only see encrypted string. There is a private key that you must keep for yourself only.

Comment: You should not encrypt it. It is read by AdMob, not by your app -- you don't write code to read this information from manifest.