# Firebase disable to see user's data

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am developing an app with Firebase authentication, relatime database and storage. What I want to do is,I as a admin/developer in Firebase console don't want to see user's privacy and sensitive data. How can I achieve this ?

Comment: As the admin of a Firebase project, you always have full access to data that you put into the project.  You can't configure the console to hide data from yourself.

Comment: But I don't want to see user's privacy, sensitive data. I don't think this is a honest way.

Comment: @Doug is right. But I assume that you don't want to see the sensitive data of the user as clear-text. Then you can encrypt that data before storing it to Firebase, and decrypt again while showing that data to the user himself.

Comment: @Akif Thank you for your  answer. Because of I am new in developing Android app, I find it hard topic to learn as a beginner. I looked Jetpack security library but find it difficult. Do you  have any suggestion for me to achive data encryption/ decryption topic as a beginner?

Comment: You can use something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175319/10659482

Comment: @Akif Thank you again.

Comment: This is the exact same question you previously asked (with an answer that matches the comments here). Please ask questions only once - if there is more info that clarifies what's being asked, add it to the question and then we can vote to re-open if it's appropriate.

Comment: I achieve my goal by using this library https://github.com/tozny/java-aes-crypto