# Android Retrofit Parameter Encryption and Decryption SHA256

Tags: android, encryption, retrofit2, sha256

In my application I am using webservices using Retrofit. I have to Encrypt Field (parameter) in Request and Decrypt it on PHP Server.

> I have to Encrypt and Decrypt version parameter.
>
> Here is my RetroApi.java

public interface RetroApi {

```
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("index.php/api/check-version")
    Call<String> getCheckVersion(@Field("version") String version, @Field("app") String app);
    
}
```

> Creating instance of RetroApi.java

```
RetroApi retroApi;

HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();

logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
OkHttpClient httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setLenient().create();
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(RetroApp.BASE_URL).addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).client(httpClient).build();

retroApi = retrofit.create(RetroApi.class);
```

> Here is the Webservice call

```
Call<String> getResult = retroApi.getCheckVersion(Constants.SP_APP_VERSION, Constants.SP_APP_NAME);
    getResult.enqueue(new Callback<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<String> call, Response<String> response) {
             
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<String> call, Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
        }
    });
```

Please assist me to accomplish this.

Comment: What problem you are facing?

Comment: @AbuYousuf I have to Encrypt the response and Decrypt it on Server

Comment: `Encrypt the response` or `Encrypt the api parameters` ?

Comment: Encrypt the api parameters

Comment: What problem you are facing in `Encrypt the api parameters` ?

Comment: I don't know how to Encrypt parameter

Comment: What exactly is your question here ? for encryption/decryption you can use a Custom interceptor or you can directly do it before sending the request. For Encryption technique you have to be specific because there is lots of out there . mostly used is `AES` .. Which Encryption you are using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically what you can do is simply encrypt your parameters with the standard Android tools. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40175319/9248201) is a simple example of how to do it from which you can start.

Basically is everything you need from an Android perspective, except for a way to store a `secret` - for that, you can use [`EncryptedSharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/security/crypto/EncryptedSharedPreferences)

After that, you can send those encrypted strings as your API arguments.

you can also create a centralized encryption factory for your requests like this:

```
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = SomeOkHttpImplementation();

Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .callFactory(new Call.Factory() {
                    @Override
                    public Call newCall(Request request) {
                        Request encryptedRequest = someFunctionToEncryptRequestOrItsArgs(request);
                        return okHttpClient.newCall(encryptedRequest);
                    }
                })
                .baseUrl(sBaseUrl)
                .build();
```

Or with custom `Interceptor` as shown [here](https://github.com/square/retrofit/issues/2094)

The problem is that you will have to find a way to decrypt them on PHP side. I am not a PHP expert but I'm sure there are ways to do that.
For example [here](https://gist.github.com/demisang/716250080d77a7f65e66f4e813e5a636) and [here](https://gist.github.com/parsibox/f69ce7679e46d1ce08576e6c972b7b9b) you can find the Java and PHP implementation of the similar ciphers.