# Android is passing values with explicit intent safe

Tags: android, android-security

Is it secure to pass `String` between activities via `Bundle` given that device is not rooted and considered secure? Can other processes like hacker's malware gain access to the data somehow?

Comment: i don't think that you need to secure data for inter exchange in activity, because it will not store anywhere while you have not just allocate memory(RAM) where hacker cant hack it!, hope you understand

Comment: try encrypting the PIN before sending via Bundle, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220761/fast-and-simple-string-encrypt-decrypt-in-java

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of intent that you can use to exchange data between activities :

- **Explicit Intents** : have specified a component (via setComponent(ComponentName) or setClass(Context, Class)), which provides the exact class to be run.
- **Implicit Intents** : have not specified a component; instead, they must include enough information for the system to determine which of the available components is best to run for that intent. (e.g. intent-filter)

If you are using Implicit Intent, there is a risk of [Intent Spoofing or Intent Interception](http://blog.palominolabs.com/2013/05/13/android-security/).

Comment: So you are implying that it is safe for explicit intent, right?

Comment: @Heisenberg Yes I think it's safe to use explicit intent, because you are specifiying which component will receive the message.