# how to store data on firebase from android?

Tags: android, firebase, chat, mbaas

This is how I store data on firebase.But can anyone suggest, how to encrypt password and save it?

```
   save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String user,pass;
            user =name.getText().toString();
            pass=password.getText().toString();

            Firebase usersRef = Ref.child("user");
          //  usersRef.child("username").setValue(user);
          //  usersRef.child("password").setValue(pass);

            Map<String,String> mUser = new HashMap<String, String>();
            mUser.put("username",user);
            mUser.put("password",pass);
            usersRef.push().setValue(mUser);

        }
    });
```

Comment: Are you want to Encrypt Password String ?

Comment: yes.
actually i want first to signup user with details like country,username,email,password,then using email and password ,i want to log to home page.then next process is create chat app

Comment: If you want to encrypt the Password then i suggest to go with this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/339004/java-encrypt-decrypt-user-name-and-password-from-a-configuration-file

Answer (score 5):

You can use any encryption method to encrypt your password but one of the best practice for encrypting password is to use `MessageDigest`.

You can use below method to convert your password with MD5 and encrypt it.

```
public static String convertPassMd5(String pass) {
        String password = null;
        MessageDigest mdEnc;
        try {
            mdEnc = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            mdEnc.update(pass.getBytes(), 0, pass.length());
            pass = new BigInteger(1, mdEnc.digest()).toString(16);
            while (pass.length() < 32) {
                pass = "0" + pass;
            }
            password = pass;
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        return password;
    }
```

Comment: thank you sir  .then while user logs in,how to decript the password ?

Comment: MessageDigest encryption is not reversible. You can not get the original string. Every time you need to encrypt it and have to match with the encrypted string. As password should be confidential.

Answer (score 0):

use message Digest for encryption of password.

Comment: Try adding a sample code along with a little explanation or documentation of the same. That makes a better answer.